# Could anyone tell the function of "that" in the following sentence?

Tags: that

> The AirTag is also far from perfect. I wish they were louder — they
> are very quiet compared with Tiles — so playing sound wasn’t very
> helpful for finding them. I also did not love **that** for most purposes,
> the AirTag requires buying a separate accessory, like a key ring, to
> hold the tracker.
>
> In contrast, the Tile has a hole punched into its corner to attach to
> a key ring or zipper head. (The $29 price tag of the AirTag is
> eclipsed by Apple’s $35 leather key ring.)

As I read an Apple AirTag review, a New York Times article, I encountered the sentences above.

I wonder what "that" in boldface works as in the sentence.

If "that" in boldface is a demonstrative pronoun as usual, it should represent the immediately preceding sentence, or the deficiency of the device's being too quiet.

But the fact seems to me a bit odd that "*I also did not love **that** for most purposes*" is immediately followed by "*the AirTag requires buying a separate accessory, like a key ring, to hold the tracker*," which can stand alone as a complete sentence, with no conjunction but only a comma.

Please explain the function here of "that" in question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*That* in the sentence is not a demonstrative pronoun. It's a **subordinating conjunction,** and functions in exactly the same way as

> She said that the AirTag requires something to hold the tracker.

> She didn't like that the AirTag requires something to hold the tracker.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/that) has a number of examples of *that* as conjunction.

Answer (score 10):

> *I also did not love* [*that for most purposes, the AirTag requires buying*
> *a separate accessory, like a key ring, to hold the tracker*].

No: this "that" is not a demonstrative but a subordinator functioning as a **marker**.

It introduces the bracketed declarative content clause functioning as complement of "love".

You could paraphrase it as *I also did not love the fact that for most purposes, the AirTag requires buying a separate accessory, like a key ring, to hold the tracker.*

Comment: I haven't heard "marker" used grammatically as you did; what do you mean by that here?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him In modern non-generative grammars, (e.g. Aarts, 2011, *Modern English Grammar*) the grammatical relations label (akin to 'Subject, Object, Determiner etc) for subordinators is 'Marker'. Note that 'subordinator' is a word category and 'Marker' is a grammatical relation (same relationship as noun to Subject for example). It just indicates that a subordinator is a meaningless left-edge Marker of a particular type of clause.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I didn't know "marker" is a grammatical relations label. I thought it was more like a generic term to use to refer to anything that marks something. In _both you and I_, for example, _both_ is a marker (of coordination) since it marks coordination.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- According to the Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar, 'marker' is defined as "A function label used for certain grammatical words. Thus in _She said that her flat is for sale_ the word _that_ is formally a subordinator, and functions as a marker." According to CaGEL p1305, 'marker' is also an appropriate label for the function of determinatives _both_ and _either_ in correlative coordination: "In the coordinations ... they function as marker of the first coordinate in correlative coordination: _both_ is paired with _and_, while _either_ is paired with _or_."

Comment: @JK2 Yes, see for example CaGEL p.954, where they give a fully labelled tree diagram.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thanks for the page number. In that diagram, Subordinator is Marker, and Clause is Head. So in a sense, "Marker: Suboridnator" is Dependent, but I don't remember CaGEL has said it is. Is "Marker: Suboridnator" Dependent of "Head: Clause" in the diagram? Or is it something else? CaGEL does say three subtypes of Dependent are Complement, Modifier and Determiner, none of which seems to include Marker: Subordinator.

Comment: @JK2 Yes, in an expanded declarative content clause, the Marker is a dependent of the clause. I haven't checked, but I'm pretty certain that they say that three *main* types of dependent are Complement, Modifier and Determiner. There are several other minor ones, for example the function 'Prenucleus' in relative and interrogative clauses.

Answer (score 1):

You may try understanding the word "*that*" in this way, with the assumption of an optional element dropped:

> I also did not love *(the fact)* **that** for most purposes, the AirTag requires buying a separate accessory, ...

Now it's an *appositive subordinate clause*, where "*the fact*" and the whole subordinate clause beginning with "*that*" refer to the same thing.

In fact, there are many more possible replacement words that fit right there, for example:

- I like (it) that ...
- I like (the assumption) that ...
- I like (the implication) that ...

As long as the word in the parentheses matches that of the subordinate clause, you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem may be that the sentence contains a grammatical error. There should be a comma after the word "that":

> I also did not love that, for most purposes, the AirTag requires buying a separate accessory, like a key ring, to hold the tracker.

The phrase "for most purposes" is an adverbial phrase, modifying the verb "requires" in the subordinate clause. A such, it can be temporarily elided for grammar analysis purposes. I will remove all prepositional phrases for this purpose:

> I also did not love that the AirTag requires buying a separate accessory.

Hopefully, it is now clear what the word "that" refers to the requirement described by "the AirTag requires buying a separate accessory." Adding back in the prepositional phrases, we can conclude that the word that refers to:

> I also did not love that, **for most purposes, the AirTag requires buying a separate accessory, like a key ring, to hold the tracker.**

If such is not clear, the other Answers can explain why: "that" is acting not as a demonstrative pronoun but a subordinator. The entire phrase (including the word "that") is functioning as a noun, and could be replaced with "I also did not love **this fact**."